# QuickFix Python plugin - use case for testing - segmentation fault error

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

We have created a test automation framework (PyTest+Quickfix) where we try to use QuickFix to send and receive messages from a Fix server. When we send bigger amount of messages (seems like random amount) we got Segmentation fault errors. For small amount of test cases it works fine. We think that the internal state of QuickFix might be wrong. (knowing about the actual sessions it keeps)

Part of the code:

```
class MyFixApp(quickfix.Application):
    class State(Enum):
        NONE = 0
        LOGGED_IN = 1
        LOGGED_OUT = 2

    def __init__(self, config_file, timeout_seconds=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.out_messages_queue = queue.Queue()  # blocking queue of quickfix outbound messages
        self.in_messages_queue = queue.Queue()  # blocking queue of quickfix inbound messages
        self.all_messages_list = list()  # list of all quickfix messages
        self.parser = simplefix.FixParser()
        self.settings = quickfix.SessionSettings(config_file)
        self.storeFactory = quickfix.FileStoreFactory(self.settings)
        self.logFactory = quickfix.FileLogFactory(self.settings)
        self.timeout_seconds = timeout_seconds
        self.sessionID = None  # This is just a stateless collection of sender comp, target comp, etc...
        self.state = FixApp.State.NONE
        # initiate the socket last, because this may call into the
        # callbacks below and we need all the members constructed
        self.initiator = quickfix.SocketInitiator(self, self.storeFactory, self.settings, self.logFactory)

    def wait_for_next_in(self, timeout=1):
        return self.in_messages_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)

    def wait_for_next_in_matching(self, subset, skipped=None, timeout=None):
        if timeout is None:
            timeout = self.timeout_seconds
        msg = self.wait_for_next_in(timeout=timeout)
        matches = FixApp.message_contains(msg, subset)
        if matches:
            return msg
        assert skipped is not None, f"expected={subset} msg={msg}"
        skipped.append(msg)
        return self.wait_for_next_in_matching(subset=subset, skipped=skipped, timeout=timeout)

    def login(self, timeout=30):
        print(f"Logging in {threading.get_ident()}")
        self.initiator.start()
        FixApp.wait_until(lambda: self.state is FixApp.State.LOGGED_IN, timeout)
        time.sleep(self.timeout_seconds)
        print(f"Logged in")

    # 30 seconds is needed for removing the session from QuickFix
    def logout(self, timeout=30):
        if not self.sessionID:
            print(f"Logging out without session")
            return
        print(f"Logging out from {self.sessionID} {threading.get_ident()}")
        self.initiator.getSession(self.sessionID).disconnect()
        FixApp.wait_until(lambda: self.state is FixApp.State.LOGGED_OUT, timeout)
        time.sleep(self.timeout_seconds)  # somehow, this needs more time. Remove this, and the following stop fails
        print(f"Logged out")
        self.initiator.stop()
        FixApp.wait_until(lambda: self.initiator.isStopped(), timeout)
        print(f"Initiator stopped")

    @staticmethod
    def wait_until(condition, timeout_sec):
        start = time.time()
        while not condition() and (time.time() - start) < timeout_sec:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        assert condition(), condition()
```

Stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7665e5b in raise () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007fffee803d14 in FIX::Initiator::connect() () at C++/Initiator.cpp:139
#3  0x00007fffee7fce74 in FIX::SocketInitiator::onStart (this=0x555556a3c5d0) at C++/SocketInitiator.cpp:89
#4  0x00007fffee801cee in FIX::Initiator::startThread (p=<optimized out>) at C++/Initiator.cpp:292
#5  0x00007ffff765b594 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff6bf400f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Failing on this line in Python (the line numbers are not according to the code attached):

```
Thread 0x00007ffff7fde540 (most recent call first):
  line 187 in wait_until
  line 153 in login
```

This is the line:

```
FixApp.wait_until(lambda: self.state is FixApp.State.LOGGED_IN, timeout)
```

Any idea is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a workaround. 
When stopping the session I have changed it to:
self.initiator.stop(True)
+ I have removed all session and log files in the end. If I do just one of these it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about possibiilty `self.out_messages_queue` and its sibling in could be filling all available memory to that thread. I mean, not sure how long and how many messages you manage, but I think there is a possibility of filling memory up if you wait enough.